# Automapper map from Source to Destination containing List of Objects

Tags: automapper, automapping, automapper-2, automapper-3

I have to create a Mapping with automapper.

```
Public class Source
{
    public string Id;
    public string Firstname;
    public string Lastname;
}
```

Destination is

```
Public class Destination
{
    public string Id;
    public Person[] persons;
}
```

Person Class is

```
Public class Person
{
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;
}
```

I am trying to create mapping

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>();
```

but I don't know how to map Firstname, Lastname to array of object Person.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>().AfterMap((s,d) => d.Person = new Person[] { FirstName = s.FirstName, LastName = s.LastName }));
```

This solution should create a new instance of `Person` however would you not be better off mapping them to a new class rather than an array?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it .

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
                .AfterMap((s, d) => d.persons= new Person[1])
                .AfterMap((s, d) => d.persons[0] = new Person{ FirstName= s.FirstName, LastName= s.LastName, RemoteId = s.Name 
                ;
```